# Can't Move Icon Nav to Right Side of Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a logo on the left of the div and the nav on the right side of the div, but I can't seem to get the nav to move to the right.

```css
.full {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.autofill {
  padding: 10px;
}

.topbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #131218;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  float: left;
  will-change: transform;
  animation: logofloat 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes logofloat {
  from {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(15px);
  }
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #25242B;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

i {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #4D4A58;
}

a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: grey;
}

a:not(.active) {
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #5433FF, #20BDFF, #6FB1FC);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="full">
  <div class="autofill" id="background">


    <div class="topbar">
      <img class="logo" src="/icons/glacier.png">
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-align-justify"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wifi"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></a>
        <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body"></div>


  </div>
```

Here is my fiddle for the project: https://jsfiddle.net/70wzxsL5/
How can I fix the aligning of the logo and nav in the division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `justify-content: space-between;` on `.topbar`

```
.topbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #131218;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/fv1ju8cw/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content: space-between;` to `.topbar`:

```css
.full {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.autofill {
  padding: 10px;
}

.topbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #131218;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between; /* Here */
}

.body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  float: left;
  will-change: transform;
  animation: logofloat 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes logofloat {
  from {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(15px);
  }
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #25242B;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

i {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #4D4A58;
}

a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: grey;
}

a:not(.active) {
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #5433FF, #20BDFF, #6FB1FC);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="full">
  <div class="autofill" id="background">


    <div class="topbar">
      <img class="logo" src="/icons/glacier.png">
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-align-justify"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wifi"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></a>
        <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body"></div>


  </div>
```